# Animating to top

Tags: jquery, html, css

js-

```
$(".inner").hover(function () {
    $(this).stop(true, false).animate({
        height: "400px"
    });
}, function () {
    $(this).stop(true, false).animate({
        height: "100px"
    });
});
```

css-

```
.inner {
    height:100px;
    width:400px;
    background-color:#333;
    margin-bottom:0px;
}

.outer {
    height:400px;
    width:400px;
    background-color:#999;
}
```

What I want to do is that the smaller box align to bottom inside the large box, and the animation take place in upper direction, but bottom, and margin-bottom are not of any help.
here is the link-

http://jsfiddle.net/4nYW6/

Comment: would be easy if you can create a fiddle ... http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: You want the white box to fill the whole space when hovered on?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
.inner {
    height:100px;
    width:400px;
    background-color:#333;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    bottom:0;
    position:absolute;
}

.outer {
    height:400px;
    width:400px;
    background-color:#999;
    position:relative;
}
```

[jsFiddle File](http://jsfiddle.net/4nYW6/1/)

Comment: I am happy you like it, please accept the answer if it is works for you.

Answer (score 1):

**[Working jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4nYW6/2/)**

Position your element:

```
.inner {
    height:100px;
    width:400px;
    background-color:#333;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.outer {
    height:400px;
    width:400px;
    background-color:#999;
    position: relative;
}
```

---

### BONUS

You can do this with pure CSS:

```
.inner {
    height:100px;
    width:400px;
    background-color:#333;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    transition: height 0.5s;
}

.outer {
    height:400px;
    width:400px;
    background-color:#999;
    position: relative;
}

.inner:hover .inner {
    height: 400px;
}
```

- The magic is `:hover` pseudo class and `transition` property.
- Check the [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4nYW6/7/).